# Is there any connector for pulling data from SharePoint 2013 to Elasticsearch

Tags: sharepoint-server

Need to connect Elasticsearch with SharePoint 2013 to pull data and provide search facility. Want to use Elasticsearch as a search engine instead of SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no such of connector. 
You can write some custom event receiver to synch the data from SharePoint and Elasticsearch throw the bulk API.

[Elasticsearch bulk API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html)

Comment: Thanks for reply. it seems one of the way to pull data from SharePoint. But i am skeptical about the performance as we will be using Event Receivers.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option available on the Internet:

A SharePoint Connector for Elasticsearch
http://www.searchtechnologies.com/elasticsearch-connector-sharepoint

No idea how well it works.  Thought I would pass it along.